# Angular and sharing objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, snap.js

I have a simple directive that is used to instantiate external plugin ([Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/)) on its element:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app
  .directive('sideMenu', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var snapper = new Snap({
            element: element[0],
            disable: 'right'
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

This is how this directive is used:

```
  <div class="snap-drawers">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="snap-content" side-menu>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse high-z">
      <button id="open-menu" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" type="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="container main-content">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>
```

So now I have this button with id "open-menu" which should open side menu on click. Opening menu looks like this:

```
snapper.open('left');
```

What would be the best and most 'angular' way to give this button access to 'snapper' variable, so it can call snapper.open on click ? One possible solution that crossed my mind is to create a controller attached to this button, then create a service that holds object 'snapper' and inject this service to directive and controller. The code would look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app
  .directive('sideMenu', function(snapper) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          snapper.initialize(element[0]);
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('btnCtrl', function($scope, snapper) {
      $scope.openMenu = function () {
          snapper.open(); 
      };
  })
  .service('snapper', function(){
      var self = this;
      this.initialize = function(element) {
          self.snap = new Snap({
              element: element[0],
              disable: 'right'
          });
      };
      this.openMenu = function() {
          self.snap.open('left');
      }
  });

      <button id="open-menu" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" type="button" ng-controller="btnCtrl">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```

Is it the proper way to do this? I am new to Angular and I'm trying to learn the best practices.

Here is a plunker so you can try on a working code: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BWau7HJV59u9tjHbPaNS?p=preview)

Comment: I think your plunker does not have updated code

Comment: Have you looked at angular-snap?